# Whatsapp on emulator - Can't setup the recorder now, please try again later

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, emulators, voice-message, 2.3.3-gingerbread

I have Whatsapp on my emulator (2.3.3 version). I got the latest update - voice messaging. However, when I try to record a message, this is what occurs.

[image]

I have no idea how to get this diagnosed. Can anything be done to help? Any audio codecs need to be installed?

Tried adding Audio Recording Support, in vain.

**UPDATE:** Tried with ICS (4.0 version). It doesn't show the error, but it doesn't send the audio message either. (The clock symbol in the right-bottom corner never turns into a tick)

Comment: I don't have Whatsapp nor Android emulator. But I want to ask a question, can you make an ordinary call in the emulator?

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved by installing the latest version of whatsapp it is 2.10.768 or 2.11.56.....you can also go to this link to download in your mobile http://www.whatsapp.com/android/

Comment: Have to test it sometime in my SDK. Right now my WhatsApp is on a phone. I am just guarding against high frequency phone number verification. But I am considering trying this out for academic interest!